# How to obtain path of files in a folder with Streams Java

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I have the code below :

```
private Path zipFiles(Path directory){
     Files.list(directory).filter(Files::isDirectory)
                      .forEach(addToZipFile(???, zipOut));
}
```

How can I obtain the path of each file ? Are there better ways of doing it using lambdas or stream ?
Thx !

Comment: You need to declare the parameter in the lambda: `.forEach(path -> addToZipFile(path, zipOut))`

Comment: And if i want the absolute path of each file ? I can't do File.getAbsolutePath()

Comment: Why not `.map(path -> path.toAbsolutePath())` after filter? Or maybe you want to convert to file first...

Comment: you can use also `Files.list(directory)
        .filter(Files::isDirectory)
        .map(Path::toAbsolutePath)
        .forEach(path -> addToZipFile(path, zipOut));`

Comment: Instead of mapping each result path to an absolute path, map the directory to an absolute path before listing, `Files.list(directory.toAbsolutePath())` then, the resulting paths are already absolute.

Comment: What if the `directory` contains subfolders? And if files are contained therein, must they added into `zipOut`?

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 8, you can use a *DirectoryStream* to iterate over the entries in a directory.

```
final Path dir = ...
try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = java.nio.file.Files.newDirectoryStream(dir, "*.java")) {
    stream.forEach(subPath -> {
       ...
    });
}
```